# Emit socket when user connected to chat

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I am trying to update the number of users connected to the chat everytime a user connects, but is not working. It works for disconnect but not for connection.
Here is the server

```js
var socket = require( 'socket.io' );
var express = require( 'express' );
var http = require( 'http' );

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer( app );

var io = socket.listen( server );
server.listen( 8080 );

connections = [];

io.sockets.on( 'connection', function( client ) {
 connections.push(client);
 console.log( "---CONNECT--- INFO --> New user connected! >>>>> USERS ONLINE: %s", connections.length);

 client.on('connection', function(data){
  io.sockets.emit('connect', {users:connections.length});
 });

 client.on('disconnect', function(data){
  connections.splice(connections.indexOf(client),1);
  console.log("---DISCONNECT--- INFO --> User disconnected >>>>> USERS LEFT: %s", connections.length);

  io.sockets.emit('disconnect', {users:connections.length});
 });

 client.on( 'message', function( data ) {
  console.log( 'Message received from: ' + data.id);

  io.sockets.emit( 'message', {id:data.id, name: data.name, avatar: data.avatar, message: data.message } );
 });
});
```

If I do like this the disconnect stops working and the server stops working properly. If I emit outside the **client.on** which would be inside the **io.sockets.on('connection')** the server will crash.
On the clients I have this:

```js
var socket = io.connect( 'http://localhost:8080' );
socket.emit('connection');

socket.on('connect', function(data){
    $("#usersOnline").html(data.users);
});
socket.on('disconnect', function(data){
    $("#usersOnline").html(data.users);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can  use [`socket.join`](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/docs/API.md#socketjoinroom-callback) and [`socket.leave`](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/docs/API.md#socketjoinroom-callback).

```
io.sockets.on( 'connection', function( client ) {
    connections.push(client);

    client.join('room', function(data){
        //
    });

    client.leave('room', function(data){
        // 
    });
});
```

Comment: It says that socket.join is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Well since none of my other answers worked for some weird reason,
try emitting an event from the client on connection.

So on the client:

```
var socket = io.connect( 'http://localhost:8080' );

socket.emit("connection");

socket.on('connect', function(data){
    $("#usersOnline").html(data.users);
});
socket.on('disconnect', function(data){
    $("#usersOnline").html(data.users);
});
```

That should work since you already have the event listener on the server side for the `client.on("connection")` event.

Comment: When I do this, it says it can't read the property data from client at socket.on('connect')...

Comment: Oh, my bad. Have you tried client.broadcast.emit()?

Comment: Still not working, I updated the current code. The same thing happens even if I do socket.emit('connection');